# How to use Eclipse Mercurial Plugin to produce a patch?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin, mercurialeclipse

I am new to Mercurial and the Eclipse Mercurial Plugin.

The thing is that I've made a change in a single file, and commit. I have two revisions of this file and I need to make a patch/diff file between the first and the second revision.

Any clues on how I can achieve this with Mercurial/Eclipse Mercurial Plugin?

King Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can through the Eclipse GUI. You can certainly export a patch for an uncommitted file or files (Team -> Export Patch).

You will have to use the command line (hg log -p) on the revision you want the patch for.